# Check notifications even if the application is not running

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, worker

I'm trying to create the following feature in my application:

I need to check for new notifications in the background (ie even when the application is closed). If the application is running, I want to inform my activity. If the application is not running, a notification should be displayed.
The user can set how often notifications should be checked.
The notification check must start itself after the device is restarted (or when the user installs the application and logs in).

I've been spending half a day on this.

I registered a BroadcastReceiver that captures the successful power-up of the device (BOOT_COMPLETE).

Furthermore, I still don't understand what I should use next (Services or Worker or something else).
How to call check every x minutes (and change minutes if user changes them in settings).

I have probably searched the whole internet and I still can't find anything that would help me. I also read about Services and Workers, but I still don't know what to use.

I will be happy for any help

btw. I get notifications by calling the API using Retrofit (**NO Firebase**):

```
private void callAPI(String request) {
        call = apiInterface.getAPIData(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<APIResponse> call, @NotNull Response<APIResponse> response) {
                ....
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<APIResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT: The notification check must end when the user logs out. If the user logs in again, the notification check starts again

Answer (score 0):

To receive push notification in background, I use a subclass of `FirebaseMessagingService`. However, it depends on the rype of the push: containing notification, data or both. Please, refer to the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

Comment: but I can't use Firebase for my project. I must call API url which returns notfications for me...

Comment: Doesn't this API call Firebase?

Comment: no, I'm not using Firebase. I'm calling my API which communicating in JSON format

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm testing the following implementation now and it looks good so far

**Boot receiver:**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()) && !getEmail(context).isEmpty())
            startService(context);
    }
}
```

**Service utils:**

```
public class utils {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationsChecker";

    public static void startService(Context context) {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationsWorker.class, getNotificationsFrequency(context), TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addTag(TAG)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
    }

    public static void stopService(Context context) {
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(TAG);
    }

    public static void restartService(Context context) {
        stopService(context);
        startService(context);
    }
}
```

and **Notifications worker:**

```
public class NotificationsWorker extends Worker {

    private final NotificationsHelper notificationsHelper;

    public NotificationsWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        Log.d("Notifications worker", "Worker initiated");
        this.notificationsHelper = new NotificationsHelper(context, APIUtils.getAPIService(), newNotifications -> {
            if (newNotification == null) {
                Log.d("Notifications checker", "newNotification is null");
            }
            else if (newNotification.getValue() != null && !newNotification.getValue())
                Log.d("Notifications checker", "newNotification is not null");
            else
                Log.d("Notifications checker", "newNotification is undefined");
                //newNotification.setValue(newNotifications);
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        notificationsHelper.prepareAPI();

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```